# Merging models and ordering by timestamps created_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am making an activity page, which will show the activity of a user and i'm wondering the best way to approach this issue of showing the different activity and ordering the activity on the created_at timestamps of all the tables merged.

at the moment i have

Controller

```
    public function getActivity()
      {
        $blogs = Blogs::where('blogs.user_id', '=', Auth::User()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        $comments = Comments::where('comments.user_id', '=', Auth::User()->id)- >orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        $forumposts = Forumpost::where('forumposts.user_id', '=', Auth::User()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')

        return view('myactivity')->withBlogs($blogs)->withComments($comments)->withForumposts($forumposts);

      }
```

View:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <p>You posted {{$blog->blogname}} at {{$blog->created_at}}</p>

@endforeach 
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>You posted {{$comment->comment}} at {{$comment->created_at}}</p>

@endforeach 
@foreach($forumposts as $forumpost)
    <p>You posted {{$forumpost->post}} at {{$forumpost->created_at}}</p>

@endforeach
```

The issue with the above code is that it is not merged on one created_at, it is essentially three different created_at lists, how do i merge them into one?

Comment: Just Use relation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$activities = $blogs->toBase()
    ->merge($comments)
    ->merge($forumposts)
    ->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

`->toBase()` is necessary because otherwise models with the same `id` would get merged.

Then differentiate them in your view:

```
@foreach($activities as $activity)
    @if($activity instanceof \App\Blogs)

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: How would the foreach work with that, obviously you would bring back the foreach($all as $something) but i want to show different <p> statements eventually depending on whether it is a $comment, $forumpost or blog

Comment: Throws a Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::merge()

on the first merge after the toBase();

Comment: You have to execute each of your three queries with `->get()`.